# Checking array in JavaScript does NOT contain any numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, integer

I'm trying to write a function that checks that there are no numbers in the array. I have the following code below but it's not working. Thanks.

```
for (var j = 0; j < inputArr.length; j++){
    if (typeof j !== "number"){
      console.log("There are no integers in the input")
    }
  }
```

Comment: You don't know if there are not any numbers, until you have verified all of them.  Logging on the first one, if it is not the only one, is premature reporting.  And that ↓

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is just to use [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
if (inputArr.every(ele => typeof ele !== "number")) {
    console.log("There are no integers in the input.");
}
```

As stated in the comments, your code fails because:

1. You say that there are no numbers in the input every time you find something which isn't a number, which means it could log multiple times, and it could still log even when there is a number.
2. You check `j`, which is the index, not the element, which is `inputArr[j]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it :)

```
function anyNumbers(inputArr) {
  for (var i; i<inputArr.length; i++) {
    if (typeof elem == 'number') {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```
anyNumbers(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']); //false
anyNumbers(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 1]); //true
```

If I have any mistakes please do not hesitate to comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.every()` and don't forget to check for a `NaN`:

```
function hasNoNumbers(array) {
    return array.every((value) => {
        return typeof value !== "number" || isNaN(value);
    });
}
```

Comment: hi I've tried this but it doesnt seem to work